# Unable to remove old kernel images due to unmet dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel

I am trying to remove old kernel images because I don't have space on the server anymore, but whenever I try to remove the images using

```
sudo apt-get remove xxx
```

I get

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-135-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-135-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-135-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The server doesn't have disk space, so it can't install the dependencies, but it also can't remove anything because of unmet dependencies? Like WTF??

Answer (score 0):

Read `man apt-get`, especially the parts about

```
   -m, --ignore-missing, --fix-missing
       Ignore missing packages; if packages cannot be retrieved or fail the integrity check after retrieval (corrupted package files), hold back those
       packages and handle the result. Use of this option together with -f may produce an error in some situations. If a package is selected for installation
       (particularly if it is mentioned on the command line) and it could not be downloaded then it will be silently held back. Configuration Item:
       APT::Get::Fix-Missing.
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually handle this problem (regarding old kernels) is by

- removing the **dependent** packages (they are mostly meta-packages anyway)
- cleaning up / freeing disk space
- reinstalling those meta-packages

In your case I'd start with

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic linux-generic
```

and after cleaning up you restore the old situation with

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

(this will pull in the other meta-packages as well)

Comment: Is there a way to define which kernel version `apt install linux-generic` will use? I am asking because the newest kernel has a problem so I told GRUB to use the older one and purged the headers for the old one. Now, when trying to reinstall `linux-generic` it will try to install the newest kernel alongside (which I want to prevent because it will not work).

Comment: @bomben You should be able to pin the version of `linux-generic` to the one that depends on the kernel you want (see man(5) apt_preferences).